# Spark filter dataframe on a condition based in the value on other rows

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with 2 column **start** and **end**, I want to find all **masters** in the dataframe.

A **master** is defined like this:
we order the dataframe by **start** ascending and **end** descending, the first row in this order is the first master, the next master is the row with a **start** value strictly bigger than the current master **end**, the same thing for this new master and so on ..

Example:

```
val columns = Seq("start", "end")
val data = Seq(
  (1, 5),
  (2, 7),
  (6, 9),
  (6, 9),
  (7, 12),
  (9, 14),
  (13, 15),
  (20, 30),
  (27, 29)
)
val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data).toDF(columns: _*)
val w = Window.orderBy(col("start").asc, col("end").desc)
df.withColumn("rank", dense_rank().over(w)).show()

+-----+---+----+
|start|end|rank|
+-----+---+----+
|    1|  5|   1|
|    2|  7|   2|
|    6|  9|   3|
|    6|  9|   3|
|    7| 12|   4|
|    9| 14|   5|
|   13| 15|   6|
|   20| 30|   7|
|   27| 29|   8|
+-----+---+----+
```

The expected results is:

```
+-----+---+
|start|end|
+-----+---+
|    1|  5|
|    6|  9|
|   13| 15|
|   20| 30|
+-----+---+
```

My solution is to get the first row (rank = 1) get it's end value and inside a while loop get the next start that's superior to the current end so the current master will be that row and so on till no master is found.

Even though this work but it's obviously not good for large data, is there a way to do it only with spark functions (without loops) ?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do it with spark, spark is used to perform actions on partitions/window and not single rows, I'm wondering though if we could think differently about this problem to make it solvable by spark.

Comment: You can implement a custom window function (extending `AggregateWindowFunction`) to do that. The problem is a different one. Spark is a map reduce framework that depends on breaking down problems into smaller chunks (aka group by / partition by) to solve these in parallel. That's not the case for your problem and I'd suggest you think about it from that perspective. Is there a way you can partition the data e.g. by the day of start? You could then introduce a post processing step that reduces the data locally (removing items after a master that streches into a new day)